# What is the Big-O for WHERE NOT IN statement?

Tags: sql, big-o

I have a simple sql query where I am selecting rows from some_table only if the id in some_table is not in the some other result set of ids.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE some_table.id NOT IN
      (SELECT id FROM
        .... whatever statement might be related to this table
      )
```

If that sub statement returns a result set such as

```
id
----
160142
160120
160093
160092
```

Is the NOT IN a O(N) where, given a "some_table.id", it starts at the top of the result set and scans each record linearly until it finds a record with the same value?  Or does it behave using a hash (like a HashSet in Java) and is able to find it in O(1)?

Does this vary by the SQL Implementation?  For example, in my application we use PostgreSQL.  But I wouldn't be surprised if it could be different in Oracle or MS SQL Server.

I would hope that this is a constant operation.  But I don't know and am just curious.

Comment: SQL is declarative. It tells you nothing about the implementation and therefore nothing about the performance. Notably, most relational DBs can use different query plans for the same query. This allows the database to optimize based on statistical trends in the data, meaning that the same query on the same system might use different plans at different points in time because data changed.

Comment: You may find the `EXPLAIN` command useful. pgAdmin will display the plan graphically when using the "Explain query" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *n* is the size of some_table and *m* is the maximum size of the sub-result, then the naive algorithm of checking each element in *n* against each element in *m* is **O(mn)**.

In reality, as jpmc26 mentioned, the underlying implementation would decide this.  If, for example, the id in *m* is indexed, it could be accessed in O(lg m) time, so *n* could be checked against *m* in O(nlg m) time.  Since you have to at least check each element of *n*, any implementation would be lower-bounded at Ω(n).

Comment: Indexes are usually B-Trees or other tree structures (at least in PostgreSQL), so it's unlikely to be O(1).

Comment: Correct, so it depends on the implementation.  It could be SQL has the results of that subquery in a array under the covers (I have no idea if it might, depends on what your query is and the SQL implementation).  I'd wager that most NOT IN implementations average n(lg m)